# Kaspersky 2012 Firewall - prompt on new connection attempts

Tags: firewall, prompt, kaspersky

How can I get Kaspersky 2012 Firewall to ask me everytime if I want to allow or deny an application to connect to the internet the first time it asks and have it remember that until the application changes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [Here](http://www.pcug.org.au/boesen/KIS/KIS.htm) is your solution.
Maybe it will help you to disable/enable all  important notifications: go settings, service, on notifications settings.
[Kaspersky Forum](http://support.kaspersky.com/kis2012/settings/firewall?print=true&qid=208284434) has this article for the firewall check out there for more. Or you can be a member there to ask this question there if it doesn't help you.

[Kaspersky Settings](http://support.kaspersky.com/kis2012/settings/appcontrol) Is the place where can you get your appropriate help hope it will work for you. Best Of luck.